# Get reference to specific cookie in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am converting an MVC 4.7.1 project into .net core 2.2.1 and I am trying to read from a specific cookie.

In my MVC 4.7.1 code I would do something like this:

```
var specificCookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookie_name"]);
```

But in .net core that collection [] returns a string, not a cookie.

So how do I get a reference to a cookie? I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IRequestCookieCollection and I have a constructor which expects a variable of that type, like so:

```
var session = new User(this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookiename"]);
```

But that line yields an error: cannot convert string to IRequestCookieCollection